# Access hidden input variable from base class

Tags: c#, asp.net

My aspx page has:

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtHidden" runat="server" />
```

This aspx page has a ascx control (inherits from `BaseUserControl`) which calls a method in the base user control class

```
base.SetHidden("test");
```

The base user control class (inherits from `System.Web.UI.UserControl)` has the SetHidden definition

```
public void SetHidden(string s)
{
  //Here I need to get a reference to txtHidden and set it's value

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public void SetHidden(string s)
{
  HtmlInputHidden myHidden = (HtmlInputHidden)this.Page.FindControl("txtHidden");
  myHidden.Value = s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtHidden" runat="server" />
```

Then you should be able to modify it server-side.

**Edit**: Ahh, I see.

Try this from your control:

```
Page.Form.FindControl("txtHidden")
```

Comment: Yes, I do have the runat attribute (edited original post). I still cannot access the txtHidden from the base class

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the page reference to the actual class of the page, then you can access the controls in it:

```
((TheActualPageClass)Page).txtHidden.Value = s;
```

Comment: The only problem with casting is that it requires that the control know which page it's on and cast to that page, creating a dependency that limits reuse of the control. Better to use Page.Form.FindControl